# PayPal sandbox takes me to live site when trying to change Payment Solution to sandbox business account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, sandbox

PayPal sandbox takes me to live site when trying to change Payment Solution to Express Checkout from PayPal Digital Goods (Express Checkout) on a sandbox business account. However, when I use the api to SetExpressCheckout it comes back with success, but then when I redirect to the paypal site it tells me that the transaction is invalid.

***This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow.***

The api username, password and signature are all correct otherwise the SetExpressCheckout wouldn't return so no idea what's going in.

Thus, I'm assuming that it is because I don't have the correct payment solution setup, i.e. Express Checkout...

Any ideas appreciated before I stick a fork in my eyeball!

Comment: Update, part fixed, not getting the transaction invalid error anymore, it was a bad character in the redirect url. However, still not able to set the payment solution to Express Checkout via the business setup in sandbox account.

Comment: Update, at the end of the day it doesn't seem to make any difference whether you have PayPal Digital Goods (Express Checkout) or Express Checkout as the payment solution on the sandbox site. It seems to work. However, when presenting an api to the world you'd think that the sandbox site would function as the live site. The fact that it takes you from sandbox to live when changing payment solution is a distraction at the very least.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying here.  Digital Goods is just a feature of Express Checkout.  Either way you're using Express Checkout.  The sandbox does function like the live site.  I use it that way myself all the time.

Comment: Why is it listed as a separate option then? https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=acct_setup/product_selection_page&fli=true  Also, If you try to change the payment solution to another payment solution via My Business Setup it changes it in your live account and not in your sandbox account. That is what I am getting at least. thus the sandbox is not behaving as it should!

Comment: You'll notice it says "PayPal for Digital Goods (Express Checkout)".  It's nothing more than adding a couple of additional parameters to your EC requests, but it's still EC.  As for your other issue, sometimes the sandbox does end up sending you to regular paypal.com instead of sandbox.paypal.com.  If you ever notice that happens, and you wind up at www.paypal.com, just add the sandbox so it becomes www.sandbox.paypal.com with whatever URL is being displayed and that should revert back to the sandbox as expected.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the reply. However, I tried editing the url and indeed it does take you to the sandbox page, but still the payment solution isn't changing. No matter, I will work around the issue for now, it is redirecting to paypal so now worries, just got to sort the return urls which don't seem to be working. :) It's fun on the funny farm!